# How to set NavigationBar overlapping the ViewController content in iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want navigationBar to overlap the root view of view controller, I have tried two methods:

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-100, 0, 0, 0);
```

and

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Neither of these options work.

So at the moment it looks like the figure below (The gradient orange is the navigationBar)[View content below the navigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzFIx.png)

However what I'd like to achieve is that the actual content of the viewController starts at the top of the screen and the gradient orange overlap the viewController.

If I still can not express it clearly, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to post a picture of exactly what you have currently and what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a navigation controller to present your view controller?

Comment: can you provide with a design how you actually need and what you have it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what u meant but maybe:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

Or set it visible from the Storyboard
[image]